# Stuck in IMobileServiceTable.ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin

I have modified the Xamarin/Azure TODO example. But the code is stuck in

> IMobileServiceTable.ToListAsync()

This is my IO class:

```
class DataIO
{
    BackgroundWorker DatabaseWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    IMobileServiceTable<UserPosition> PositionTable;
    MobileServiceClient client;


    public DataIO()
    {
        Init();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);
        PositionTable = client.GetTable<UserPosition>();
    }


    async void AddEntry(UserPosition entry)
    {
        await PositionTable.InsertAsync(entry);
    }

    public async Task<List<UserPosition>> GetEntries()
    {


        List<UserPosition> Entries = await PositionTable.ToListAsync();

        return Entries;
    }

    public async void DeleteEntry(UserPosition entry)
    {
        await PositionTable.DeleteAsync(entry);
    }

    public async void AddToDatabase(UserPosition item)
    {
        await PositionTable.InsertAsync(item);
    }
}
```

The debugger dosen't neither step over it nor throws an error.
How to handle that?

In an earlier call, there wasn't any problem.

EDIT:
I've rewritten the GetEntries() method to:

```
    public async Task<List<UserPosition>> GetEntries()
    {

        Task<List<UserPosition>> task = PositionTable.ToListAsync();


        List<UserPosition> entries = await task;

        return entries;
    }
```

according to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await). But the debugger just stays in the line

```
Task<List<UserPosition>> task = PositionTable.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: How have you modified the TODO example? If it is stuck, it sounds a lot like a deadlock scenario. Could you maybe try adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your async calls? Also please add more details about what you are doing and how you are calling this method.

Comment: I added my created class. The online table has entries (I added them before). But now I don't get data from azure anymore. List<UserPosition> Entries = await PositionTable.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
doesn't change anything...

Comment: Yeah, you are doing it wrong. Read up on how to use `async` and `await` keywords.

Comment: @Christoph, Apart from the other mistakes in the that class, how is the `GetEntries()` being called? Most likely you are mixing blocking and async code

Comment: I'm calling it in an async method with "Entries = await IOController.GetEntries();". Sorry I don't get the mistake with async and await :-(

Comment: @Christoph if it is staying on that line it appears to be a deadlock. Something higher up the call stack is cause that line to block.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `IMobileServiceTable.ToListAsync()` would send the request as follows for retrieving the result:

```
Get https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/tables/UserPosition
```

[image]

I would recommend you using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to collect the network traces when calling `IMobileServiceTable.ToListAsync()`. Also, you could access the table endpoint from your mobile app via the browser to make sure your mobile app could work as expected. Additionally, here is a great tutorial about [Handling Data in Mobile Clients](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/client/), you could refer to it.